# Periodically hid_hw_raw_request in kernel module, how to?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, atomic

I'm writing a kernel module that need to ask an hid raw device periodically.
 I tried hrtimer and a simple timer and each time I call `hid_hw_raw_request` I got a `"BUG: scheduling while atomic"`.

If I try the same function outside my timer function (eg in the `init`), it works fine (no bug).

How could periodically call this function without generating any bug ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a work queue to issue your **hid_hw_raw_request** as deferred work. This can be done as in the following example module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>

static void hid_work_handler(struct work_struct *hid_work);

static struct workqueue_struct *hid_workqueue;
static DECLARE_WORK(hid_work, hid_work_handler);

static void hid_work_handler(struct work_struct *hid_work)
{
        ...
        hid_hw_raw_request(...);
        ...
}

static int __init hid_work_init(void)
{
        if (!hid_workqueue)
                hid_workqueue = create_singlethread_workqueue("hid_workqueue");

        if (hid_workqueue)
                queue_work(hid_workqueue, &hid_work);

        return 0;
}

static void __exit hid_work_exit(void)
{
        if (hid_workqueue) {
                flush_workqueue(hid_workqueue);
                destroy_workqueue(hid_workqueue);
        }
}

module_init(hid_work_init);
module_exit(hid_work_exit);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("hid_work_test");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Note that for the real implementation you'll need to create your own data struct with an included **struct work_struct** to be queued. This data struct will likely contain the hiddev, buffer, etc. that the **hid_work_handler** needs to do the actual transfer. See LDD3 Chapter 7 for more details (albeit syntax of calls is outdated, the basic explanation still applies).

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot for you detailed answer ! I will give a try asap but it looks exactly to what I was searching for !